# Sort List of Ruby Hashes by Key's Value

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
[{"day":3,"count":4.75},{"day":1,"count":5.5},{"day":2,"count":3.0},{"day":4,"count":5.0},{"day":5,"count":7.2},{"day":6,"count":7.666666666666667},{"day":0,"count":6.75}]
```

I want sort this list of hashes by the "day" key values.

The final output should look like:

```
[{"day":0,"count":6.75},{"day":1,"count":5.5},{"day":2,"count":3.0},{"day":3,"count":4.75},{"day":4,"count":5.0},{"day":5,"count":7.2},{"day":6,"count":7.666666666666667}]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You haven't presented valid Ruby nor shown what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a block to #sort on your array.

```
array.sort do |a, b|
    a[:day] <=> b[:day]
end
```

This will iterate over your hashes and compare using your `:day` key.

P.S. I would use nicer symbol syntax in your arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
hsh.sort_by{|h| h['day'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{"day":3,"count":4.75},{"day":1,"count":5.5},{"day":2,"count":3.0},{"day":4,"count":5.0},{"day":5,"count":7.2},{"day":6,"count":7.666666666666667},{"day":0,"count":6.75}]

a.sort{|x,y| x["day"] <=> y["day"] }
```

but your original should be
{"day" =>3, "count" =>4.75}